# Service grid in a micro services environment

Tags: singleton, consul, netflix-eureka, gridgain, spring-cloud-netflix

We are using apache ignite as a IMDG in our micro services environment.

For scalability and load balancing we are considering to use a service registry like eureka or consul which is supported by spring cloud for the deployed micro services.

There is a concept of service grid providing support for node singleton and cluster singleton in apache ignite.

I also see WCF,weblogic  and JBoss to having the same sort of features.

I am trying to understand what these service grids are and if i can use them to achieve the same benefits as the eureka service registry provided by netflix and supported by spring cloud.

Can someone guide if i can achieve the same using service grid in apache ignite.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use Apache Ignite Service Grid for the same purposes as Eureka. Eureka is used for load balancing and service discovery over WAN. Using Ignite clusters spanning over multiple AWS zones and remote client machines is not the most efficient way of using it.

More information on Ignite Service Grid can be found here - http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/service-grid

Thanks!

UPD (for the 1st comment):
You cannot (in most cases) span and effectively use Ignite over WAN networks with high latencies and lower throughput characteristics.

As far as local clusters in non-cloud environments - go ahead! This is the best environment for systems of such kind.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, can you clarify if it is not effective only in specific coud environments like AWS or generally in cloud. Also,can we consider using it for a local cluster of service instances, in a non-cloud environment.